# Meaning of a "cheap person"

Tags: meaning

[image]

[image]

What is the meaning of this, i have tried to search on dictionary but couldn't find it.
Context as in image attached.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheap+person

Savior is referred to the person she is attacking.

Comment: You would better looking at [cheap](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page @ dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cheap), there are two possible meanings for using "cheap" to describe a person:

> 5.
>   embarrassed; sheepish: *He felt cheap about his mistake.*
>
> 8.
>   stingy; miserly: *He's too cheap to buy his own brother a cup of coffee.*

Before I found that page I was only thinking of "cheap person" to be a variation of "cheapskate" but now I have a feeling that the translator of the manga page used "cheap person" to imply that the person is sheepish, to explain why she escaped.

EDIT:

If you scroll down that page, there is an additional meaning, right under "World English Dictionary":

> 8.
>   *informal*  mean; despicable: *a cheap liar*

So, "cheap person" can mean "despicable person" as well.

Comment: I agree with "despicable".  "Stingy" really doesn't fit in this context at all, though.

Answer (score 2):

A *frugal* person spends no more than necessary.

A *cheap* person tries to be frugal, but sometimes ends up spending *less* than necessary.

---

This is based on a reading of "She escaped in the blast." as referring to the assailant, not the savior.  I.e. the savior used enough power to dissuade the assailant, but not enough to disable her (so that she could be captured).

Comment: +1. This is the right meaning, but I still didn't know what they were getting at in the cartoon. I think your explanation is probably right. This is kind of a misuse of the word though. It really isn't applied to non-financial situations. `lazy` would be more appropriate in this case. I don't suppose the word bubbles were translated from another language?

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe it is a financial situation.  Weapons are expensive.  But "cheap" can be used in the context of transferring anything of values.

Comment: In the manga she is really attacking the her savior.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap has the sense of not willing to put forth effort to act in a classy or ethical manner -- tawdry might be a synonym.  Magnanimous would be an antonym.